# merging two channels data from audiobuffer in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

how can we merge data from two channels of audio buffer to an arrayBuffer so we can convert that arrayBuffer to Blob?

```
var floatarray1 = new Float32Array();
audioBuffer.copyFromChannel(floatarray1,0);

var floatarray2 = new Float32Array();
audioBuffer.copyFromChannel(floatarray2,1);
```

how can we merge "floatarray1" and "floatarray2" which are being copied from an "audioBuffer" into a single "arrayBuffer"?

Answer (score 1):

To "merge" two channels of audio into a single channel. This can be called audio "mix".
A very simple mix is just to add each corresponding sample together, like this:

```
var mixed = new Float32Array(floatarray1.length)

for(i=0;i<floatarray1.length;i++){
    mixed[i] = floatarray1[i]+floatarray2[i]
}
```

If the audio volume is pretty high, and is possibly "overflow", you may need to pick a factor (<1.0) to multiplied with each sample, to reduce the risk of overflow:

```
const voladj = 0.6
var mixed = new Float32Array(floatarray1.length)

for(i=0;i<floatarray1.length;i++){
    mixed[i] = (floatarray1[i]+floatarray2[i])*voladj
}
```

I think this simple algorithm is already good enough to calculate it in Javascript.

Hope this helps.